# Connect J2ME to database

Tags: database, java-me

I want some help that is related to [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition).

I don’t know a lot about J2ME and now I am required to do a mobile application (it is a course project).

My application must be connected to the database, so I don’t know what should I do to do this project!

Some students said that I should to do a web server that connects to the database and the mobile application will communicate with the web server to get the information from the database.

“I want really to know how to connect the application (in the mobile) by the database “?

What are the steps that I can follow to design the application? For example, first do the database and then the application?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Database support in the J2ME platform. But if you want to store data in the phone there is Record Store (known as [RMS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/)) even though the capacity is less.

If you really want to use a database either you have to use a web server which is based on the HTTP protocol, or you have to write a socket based application which runs on TCP.

If it's a database oriented application then you have design the database based on what all the data you are planning to get from application as input.